# LISP - Check Roman Numeral Converter for valid Roman Numeral

Tags: validation, lisp, common-lisp

I have a lisp program that converts Roman Numerals into decimal form. It works great for valid inputs, however I'm not sure how to check to see if the input is a valid Roman Numeral. Currently when given an invalid input ("MIM") for example, it still tries to incorrectly convert it. I need it to instead return an ERROR message.

```
(defun mapRomanToDecimal (chars nums string)
  (loop as char across string
        as i = (position char chars)
        collect (and i (nth i nums))))

(defun parseThroughRoman (R)
  (loop with nums = (mapRomanToDecimal "IVXLCDM" '(1 5 10 50 100 500 1000) R)
    as (A B) on nums if A sum (if (and B (< A B)) (- A) A)))

(defun romanToDecimal (RomanNumeral)
    (format t "~d~%" (parseThroughRoman (numlist-to-string RomanNumeral))))

(defun numlist-to-string (lst)
  (when lst
     (concatenate 'string 
             (write-to-string (car lst)) (numlist-to-string (cdr lst)))))


(romanToDecimal '(C D V)) -> 405
(romanToDecimal '(M I M)) -> 1999
```

Comment: (1) Note that `"MIM"` and `'(M I M)` are different values (string vs list). (2) You need to be clear about the rule that specifies what makes an input valid or not. Then you'll be able to add checks. (3) style: dash-separated-names, no camelCase, please.

Comment: I know MCM is valid for 1900, then why are MIM not valid for 1999?

Comment: Also note that Common Lisp's format can already [print as Roman numerals](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cba.htm).

Answer (score 2):

A little bit about style...

- data type conversion is often not necessary
- code can easily be more generic

Example:

```
(defvar *roman-chars* "IVXLCDM")
(defvar *roman-nums*  '(1 5 10 50 100 500 1000))

(defun roman-numeral-to-decimal (roman-numeral)
  (let ((i (position (coerce roman-numeral 'character) *roman-chars*)))
    (and i (nth i *roman-nums*))))

(defun map-roman-numerals-to-decimal (roman-numerals)
  (map 'list #'roman-numeral-to-decimal roman-numerals))

(defun roman-to-decimal (roman)
  (loop as (A B) on (map-roman-numerals-to-decimal roman)
        if A sum (if (and B (< A B)) (- A) A)))
```

This means you can use it with lists of symbols/characters/strings, strings, vectors symbols/characters/strings:

```
CL-USER 20 > (roman-to-decimal '(C D V))
405

CL-USER 21 > (roman-to-decimal '("C" "D" "V"))
405

CL-USER 22 > (roman-to-decimal '(#\C #\D #\V))
405

CL-USER 23 > (roman-to-decimal "CDV")
405

CL-USER 24 > (roman-to-decimal #(c d v))
405
```